# Replacing every multiplication with a custom instruction

Tags: c++

I have some basic C++ code (included below). I want to be able to replace every multiplication that occurs (including within the cos function included in math.h) with a custom instruction. I am able to directly call the custom instruction within my main, but the 'cos' will still use the old multiplication instruction.

I have considered doing operator overloading, but I was unable to make this function properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 2;
  int b = 5;
  std::cout << "mult: " << a * b << std::endl;
  std::cout << "cos: " << cos(b) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

What is the best way to approach implementing this custom instruction in the way I would like?

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to do this? (P.S: I'm pretty sure what you want is impossible, operator overloading wont work for base types, so unless you refactor the entire code to use custom types over which you have control...)

Comment: NIOSII does not support floating point hardware multiplication. I am introducing hardware to do so and would like to accelerate my cos calculation as well. I currently have a custom instruction so I can do `a*b` as `custom_instruction(a,b)`, but as cos is within the math.h library, I cannot change those multiplications

Comment: How do you know there are multiplies in the version of `std::cos` your compiler is using? Do you have access to the source of your compiler? It may be easier to get it to use your `custom_instruction(a,b)` where it would otherwise software multiply, and not actually change your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to substitute some functionalities without touching your code. It depends, off course, on how you're building your code.
Assuming that you're using Linux you can inject features using LD_PRELOAD.

Here is a nice explanation on how to do that:

https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/

If that does not apply exactly to your case, you can grab some ideas or simply learn this cool feature.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cos` provides overloads only for the built-in floating point types `float`, `double`, `long double` (any integral type also can be provided, but it's cast to `double` internally). You cannot overload operators for built-in types. This means that you can't do what you are asking.

The best you can get is to write your own numeric class that overloads the multiplication operator and write your own trigonometric functions for it using your alternative multiplication implementation.